# GetEventStore error "Log record at actual pos X has too large length"

Tags: eventstoredb

When performing `ReadAllEventsForward` on a restored database, I receive the following error:

```
[PID:18628:030 2014.10.29 11:13:41.535 ERROR StorageReaderWorker ] Error during processing ReadAllEventsForward request.
System.ArgumentException: Log record at actual pos 83405 has too large length: 892612896 bytes, while limit is 16777216 bytes. Something is seriously wrong in chunk 0-0 (C:\Event Store\hydra\chunk-000000.000000).
   at EventStore.Core.TransactionLog.Chunks.TFChunk.TFChunk.TFChunkReadSide.TryReadForwardInternal(ReaderWorkItem workItem, Int64 actualPosition, Int32& length, LogRecord& record) in c:\BuildAgent1\work\oss\windows\releasebuilds\src\EventStore\EventStore.Core\TransactionLog\Chunks\TFChunk\TFChunkReadSide.cs:line 484
   at EventStore.Core.TransactionLog.Chunks.TFChunk.TFChunk.TFChunkReadSideUnscavenged.TryReadClosestForward(Int64 logicalPosition) in c:\BuildAgent1\work\oss\windows\releasebuilds\src\EventStore\EventStore.Core\TransactionLog\Chunks\TFChunk\TFChunkReadSide.cs:line 103
   at EventStore.Core.TransactionLog.Chunks.TFChunkReader.TryReadNextInternal(Int32 retries) in c:\BuildAgent1\work\oss\windows\releasebuilds\src\EventStore\EventStore.Core\TransactionLog\Chunks\TFChunkReader.cs:line 84
   at EventStore.Core.Services.Storage.ReaderIndex.ReadIndex.EventStore.Core.Services.Storage.ReaderIndex.IReadIndex.ReadAllEventsForward(TFPos pos, Int32 maxCount) in c:\BuildAgent1\work\oss\windows\releasebuilds\src\EventStore\EventStore.Core\Services\Storage\ReaderIndex\ReadIndex.cs:line 767
   at EventStore.Core.Services.Storage.StorageReaderWorker.ReadAllEventsForward(ReadAllEventsForward msg) in c:\BuildAgent1\work\oss\windows\releasebuilds\src\EventStore\EventStore.Core\Services\Storage\StorageReaderWorker.cs:line 194
```

The error appeared in yellow on the command line and I retrieved it from the logs.

The system I backed up was running, a single stream accepting an event every few seconds. I used the backup instructions on the [GetEventStore](http://docs.geteventstore.com/introduction/database-backup/) and followed them carefully. I restored the database into a sub folder of the GetEventStore installation and used the following command line:

```
"C:\Event Store\EventStore.SingleNode.exe" --db .\myDatabaseName
```

In the command line output, I saw that the database in use was correct. The code that is calling GetEventStore is C# .NET over HTTP and it is doing a re-project, failing on the first call to GetEventStore.

What have I missed/done wrong?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This is a hardware related issue and I ran into it myself. Got into a big rabbit hole trying to solve - one thing led to another. Among other things, I tried [this](https://www.eventstore.com/blog/disabling-disk-caching-in-ubuntu) but didn't work. Eventually, I gave up and used the Docker image instead and things were really streamlined since I started using it. I wish I would have started my project with Docker image in the first place.

If you run into this issue, please do yourself a favor and use the Docker image instead

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue when I tried to restore eventstore database files. I could solved it by removing  truncate.chk and renaming chaser.chk to truncate.chk.

```
      rm  /var/lib/eventstore/truncate.chk
      mv  /var/lib/eventstore/chaser.chk /var/lib/eventstore/truncate.chk      
      # for pod & docker
      chown -R 1000:1000 /var/lib/eventstore
```